# combobox input of form using array variable in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

```
<?php
$types_size=sizeof($types)-1;
$array_type=' ';
while($types_size!=-1)
{
$array_type.='"'.$types[$types_size]["Type"]["name_type"].'", ';
$types_size--;
}
echo $array_type; 
echo $this -> form -> input ('id_type', array('options' => array($array_type)));
echo $this -> form -> input ('id_type', array('options' => array(shoes, shirts, jeans,)));
?>
```

- I created $array_type to store types data.
- I got the types data : "shoes", "shirts", "jeans",
- I wanna created an combobox input with 3 values just like the second input

Question : The code above doesn't show as I expected. The combobox of the first input shows only one value: shoes, shirts, jeans, not like the expected second input
Hopefully someone understand my problem !!!

Answer (score 1):

In the above code you will be realized that `$array_type` is a string variable not an array.
You should declare an array variable using `$array_type = array()` not `$array_type = ''`

You can try to print `$array_type` variable and verify whether it is an array or a string.

Now your code should looks like:

```
<?php
$types_size=sizeof($types)-1;
$array_type= array();
while($types_size!=-1)
{
    $array_type[] = $types[$types_size]["Type"]["name_type"];
    $types_size--;
}
//echo $array_type; // if you echo an array variable it will print `Array`. 
//Use print_r() to print an array 
print_r($array_type);
echo $this -> form -> input ('id_type', array('options' => $array_type));
echo $this -> form -> input ('id_type', array('options' => array(shoes, shirts, jeans,)));
```

?>

Comment: Thanks so much Arun Jain !!! This is the first time I post question on this forum and I got just what I need !!!

Comment: Kindly accept this answer. So that others can considered it as an answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$types_size=sizeof($types)-1;
$array_type= array();
while($types_size!=-1)
{
    $array_type[] = $types[$types_size]["Type"]["name_type"];
    $types_size--;
}
//echo $array_type; // if you echo an array variable it will print `Array`. 
//Use print_r() to print an array 
print_r($array_type);
echo $this -> form -> input ('id_type', array('options' => $array_type));
echo $this -> form -> input ('id_type', array('options' => array(shoes, shirts, jeans,)));
```